# Change innerHTML if quantity is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I have written the following code that changes an output (innerHTML) when the quanitity changes.

```js
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'qty_output_text' );
 
function qty_output_text() {
   global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type('variable') && is_product() ) {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var quantita_iniziale = $('[name=quantity]').val();
         $( '[name=quantity]' ).change( function(){
             var quantita_iniziale = $('[name=quantity]').val();
             document.getElementById("test123").innerHTML= quantita_iniziale+"K = "+quantita_iniziale+" test";
        });

    </script>
    <?php
   }
}
```

If I then change the quantity in the product, then the output is correct.

The product has 2 variations. If I select variation 1, the minimum quantity is set to 15. However, my script does not recognize this change and therefore does not output the correct number. Do you know what I can do here? The minimum number should also change [name=quantity] or not?

**EDIT:**
Here is a video of my problem https://www.veed.io/view/e70ba12f-84e4-4a21-8966-bb1f332077ce

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the value of the element you just changed.

You can do that by using `this`. If you want to display **both** quantities in your div then you need to query both elements separately and get each of their values.

```js
var quantita_iniziale = $('[name=quantity]').val();
$('[name=quantity]').change(function() {
  var quantita_iniziale = $(this).val();
  document.getElementById("test123").innerHTML = quantita_iniziale + "K = " + quantita_iniziale + " test";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="quantity">
  <option> Change me </option>
  <option value="1">1 </option>
  <option value="2">2 </option>
</select>

<select name="quantity">
<option> Change me </option>
  <option value="1">1 </option>
  <option value="2">2 </option>
</select>
<p id="test123">

</p>
```

Comment: Hello,

thank you very much for your answer.  Unfortunately, this. did not work. The output is still unchanged.

Comment: I have linked a video of my problem. Maybe I didn't explain it in enough detail.